# Apply slickgrid formatting to a specific row

Tags: slickgrid

Is it possible to apply formatting to a specific row in Slickgrid?

I am aware you can apply formatting rules via columns - but I need to apply a format rule to a row.

i.e. I have a "totals" row on my grid - so I want to make the row bold or something to stand out from the other rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy - https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Providing-data-to-the-grid.

In short, implement `getItemMetadata` and specify the `formatter` override based on the row number.  This is exactly what the slick.groupitemmetadataprovider.js does when used in conjunction with the DataView.